# Invalid base64 decoding

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to decode a base64 string but the result contains some invalid characters.

The string is

```js
decodeString=`bWFpbi5jOiBJbiBmdW5jdGlvbiDigJhtYWlu4oCZOgptYWluLmM6NToyMzog
              ZXJyb3I6IGV4cGVjdGVkIOKAmDvigJkgYmVmb3JlIOKAmH3igJkgdG9rZW4K
              ICAgIDUgfCBwcmludGYoIkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkISIpCiAgICAgIHwgICAgICAg
              ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIF4KICAgICAgfCAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg
              ICAgOwogICAgNiB8IAogICAgNyB8IH0KICAgICAgfCB+ICAgICAgICAgICAg
              ICAgICAgICAgIAo=`
console.log(atob(decodeString));
```

The output that I am getting is:

```
main.c: In function â€˜mainâ€™:

main.c:5:23: error: expected â€˜;â€™ before â€˜}â€™ token

5 | printf("Hello World!")
  |                       ^
  |                       ;
6 | 
7 | }
  | ~
```

The decoded string is a compiler output. Everything expect " ' "(single quotes) are printing just fine.
Please help

Comment: What are you trying to do inside the function which is decoding this string?
Moreover, how is this relevant to reactjs, please use correct tags for better reachability.

Comment: you can check your decoded result from here https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: I am designing a compiler in react js. I am using the judge0 api which sends compiler output in base64 encoded string. I simplified the question by just pasting a specific string else the result always gives the single quotes as an unreadable character

Comment: @SifatHaque yeah i checked it is giving correct result

Comment: @Rishav - [a lot of dupes](https://www.google.com/search?q=atob+%C3%A2%C2%80) are found when you just search for atob and â€

Comment: From the dupe I posted: `const b64DecodeUnicode = str => decodeURIComponent(atob(str).split('').map(c =>
'%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2)).join(''));
`